# Program crashes when trying to print a double (but other types are ok)

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64

I am trying to call a C function from assembler code (Linux x86-64). In the assembler code, types are encoded by the 3 LSB. The purpose of the C function is simply to easily print typed values. Here is the function:

```
int print(long i) {
  int type = i & 7;
  long val = i >> 3;
  double c;
  switch(type) {
  case 0:
    printf("%d\n", val);
    break;
  case 1:
    if (!val)
      printf("false\n");
    else if (val == 1) 
      printf("true\n");
    else if (val == 2)
      printf("nil\n");
    break;
  case 2:
    printf("%s\n", (char*)(val + 8));
    break;
  case 6:
    c = *(double*) val;
    //printf("%d\n", (int)c); /* no seg fault */
    //printf("%f\n", 1.0); /* seg fault */
    printf("%f\n", c); /* seg fault */
    break;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

I have been using it without any problem up to now with string pointers so I know it's not a memory problem, but its my first time using the `%xmm` registers, so I may be doing something wrong there. Here is the relevent calling segment:

```
    movsd   _DB1(%rip), %xmm4
    movsd   _DB2(%rip), %xmm5
    addsd   %xmm5, %xmm4
    movsd   %xmm4, (%r12)
    leaq    6(, %r12, 8), %rdi
    addq    $8, %r12
    call    print
##### ... #####
    .data
_DB1:
    .double 2
_DB2:
    .double 3
```

`%r12` points to memory allocated in the heap. The weirdest thing is that if I convert the double to an integer before calling `printf`, there is no segmentation fault (uncommenting the line in case 6 and commenting the line below) AND it comes out with the right result (5). During debugging, I found the segmentation fault occured within the subroutines of the `printf` function where I can't see the code. Also even if I define a random double, I can't print it.

At this point any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: In case 0 and case 1 you handle `val` as regular variable e.g.: `printf("%d\n", val);` But here in case 6 as pointer: `c = *(double*) val;` I think you just mean: `c = val;`. Further this code is full of magic numbers. You should consider using an enum for your types.

Comment: Since I'm passing the location of the double in the memory to the C function, I need to convert it as a pointer, if I do `c = val` i won't get a double

Comment: Even if the cast was `*(double *)&val`, it would have undefined behaviour. Don't do this.

Comment: @Hadron: Okay that isn't able to see with the code provided without that explanation. If you pass the address you corrupt it by: `long val = i >> 3;` or did you do something before to it we didn't see here?

Comment: @Andre Kampling I am loading the address here
`leaq    6(, %r12, 8), %rdi`
as you can see I am shifting it left by 3, and adding 6, when I get it in the parameter I can shif it back without loosing part of it

Comment: does the pointer survive `>>3`? I mean, isn't the original address something like 0x800... ruined by that *8 scale? Also why `addq    $8, %r12`? I'm just waking up, but I don't see why. How about using two arguments, just for the sake of clarity and simplicity? (value, type).

Comment: @Ped7g I am adding `$8` to `%r12` so that further allocation can be made, and yes the pointer does survive, it only requires 6 of the 8 bytes if I remember correctly

Comment: Ah.. ok, I got it... so in debugger, is the address restored correctly? I guess it is, and the upper b63..b60 are zeroes (must be all four of them as `>>` is signed in this case). Then it depends how you allocated that buffer for values at `r12`, but that would crash upon write probably. Also I guess it's aligned. So the most likely crash reason will be not adhering to the remaining rules of your platform x64 calling convention, most likely check the stack (`rsp`) alignment ahead of `call print`.

Comment: @AndreKampling that's why my comment starts with "even if"...

Comment: In any case now that I realized what you Hadron are after, this is the wrong way to do it. First of all, use *`uintptr_t`* instead.

Comment: Also... this type encoding ... must be cumbersome in the asm? Isn't much easier to create `print_long`, `print_bool`, `print_double` variants and just call the wanted one, with proper argument type and no shifting + type encoding?

Comment: Well this is part of a compiler for lua (a not typed language) so there is no way to know before hand what the value will be holding, hence the integrated type

Comment: @Ped7g Thank you for your suggestion! It was the stack alignment. I just had to align it on 16. I don't get why the problem never occured before though

Comment: Depends on the `printf` implementation, probably it didn't use any SSE for integral types, so the first misaligned access happened when it created some local `double` on stack and accessed it by some SSE ... (just guessing, I didn't ever study any implementation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of the code fragment depends on how the pointers to `double` and strings are encoded into the `long` value `i`, and other considerations. It is highly non-portable.

You compute `long val = i >> 3;` which has implementation-defined behavior for negative values of `i` and produces pointer values with `0` or `1` high bits when later cast as `(double*)` or `(char*)`. While some of the high order bits in pointer representations are ignored on common architectures, relying on this behavior is unsafe and would fail on 32-bit intel PCs.  It might be a better idea to ensure that pointers are aligned on 8-byte boundaries (at least) and just mask off low order bits or otherwise adjust the values before casting as `(double*)` or `(char*)`.

It would also be more portable to use `uintptr_t` instead of `long` in case `long` is smaller than `void*`, as is the case on 64-bit Windows systems.

Comment: Right shift of a signed integer is implementation-defined, not undefined.  You will get a value, and nasal demons are not a possibility.  (On pretty much every existing C implementation, you get an arithmetic right shift, though, shifting in copies of the sign bit.)